# 2 arguments in push_back

Tags: vector, push-back

I am trying to put 2 arguments inside a vector using push_back but its giving me an error since the function is allowed to take only one argument. How can I pass 2 arguments??

Vertex Class:

```
template <class VertexType, class EdgeType> class Vertex{
public:
std::vector<std::pair<int, EdgeType>> VertexList;
};
```

Outside Vertex Class inside Main():

```
project3::Vertex<string, string> v1("v1");
v1.VertexList.push_back(1,"e1");
```

Error is :

error C2661: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
IntelliSense: too many arguments in function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
v1.VertexList.push_back(std::pair<int, EdgeType>(1,"e1"));
```

Comment: Or, slightly fewer angle brackets: `.push_back(make_pair(1, "e1"))`

Comment: I tried the above code suggested by Ernest Friedman - Hill... It worked. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try push_back(make_pair(1, string("e1")));